# I want to combine 2 datasets of numbers to another dataset without a common variable

Tags: merge, sas, concatenation

I'm de-identifying some things. I have a dataset with my identifiers (ID1 and ID2)
For each ID1 there are multiple ID2s
I found the number of unique ID1s and created random numbers using ranuni and seed and output them into a dataset. I did the same for ID2. 
Now that I have ID1 and ID2 I want to create an excel file that will output ID1 ID2 de-identified ID1 and de-identified ID2. I was going to merge but I don't have anything to merge on (except observation). So I'm quite confused. Suggestions would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Example data set

```
data real_data;
  input ID1  ID2;
  datalines;    
1   11    
1   12    
1   13    
1   14    
1   15    
2   11   
3   13
3   14    
3   17
;;;;
run;
```

Comment: I thought about using 1-1 merge but I'm worried that it will only match up to the shorter ID1

Comment: Okay, now what are you merging to that?  What do those dataset(s) look like?

Comment: I created a deidentified dataset (2 of them) 1 for ID1 and 1 for ID2 (with no duplicates). I have then created 1 Dateset that is just ID1 and it's randomly generated deidentified new ID (which is just a number that doesn't mean anything without the key) and another one for ID1, ID2 and the deidentified new ID2. So I think I could now just merge on ID1. I think

Comment: and I think I've got it thanks a TON Joe. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side by side merge wouldn't work here because you have fewer ID1 than ID2.  Unless you can easily make a dataset of the combination of id1 and id2, you can't really do this.

First off, I wouldn't do the deidentification this way.  You can do it within the same datastep.  Basically, create a random sorting parameter (two, one each for id1 and id2), then sort by that, then assign sequential IDs at that point.  Sequential IDs applied to a randomly sorted dataset are de-identified by nature.

If you want to do it with a separate dataset, I would construct your random IDs in a format that converted a sequential 1:num(ID_1) to ID1_DEID and same for ID2.  Then make a counter that increments by one for each ID1 and another for each ID2, and in each case PUT the counter with the format, generating the de_id value.

Comment: I have my data such that ID1 is already repeated multiple times (1 time for each ID2 that it goes with ID1 is like a person ID2 is an event associated with the person) . Do I need to go in and create a variable for each and every ID1?

Comment: You should include an example of your data (say, 5 ID1s and some ID2s associated with them and then the de-id datasets you would create for those) if you want the best and most useful answers.

Comment: I've tried to I'm newer on here I can't make tables can't find how to make tables. Can't give real data because it's private.

Comment: Create some dummy data in excel or your favourite spreadsheet app, then paste it back into your question here, then highlight it and press ctrl + K.

Comment: Preferably in a datalines statement, if possible, as I edited your first bit above.